# Complicated for loop to be ported to a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I have the next for nested loop and I would like to port it to CUDA to be run on a GPU

```
int current=0;
int ptr=0;

for (int i=0; i < Nbeans; i++){
  for(int j=0;j< NbeamletsPerbeam[i];j++){

     current = j + ptr;

     for(int k=0;k<Nmax;k++){
        ......
     }

     ptr+=NbeamletsPerbeam[i];
 }   
}
```

I would be very happy if any body has an idea of how to do it or how can be done.
We are talking about Nbeams=5, NbeamletsPerBeam around 200 each.

This is what I currently have but I am not sure it is right...

```
 for (int i= blockIdx.x; i < d_params->Nbeams; i += gridDim.x){
            for (int j= threadIdx.y; j < d_beamletsPerBeam[i]; j+= blockDim.y){
                 currentBeamlet= j+k;
                 for (int ivoxel= threadIdx.x; ivoxel < totalVoxels; ivoxel += blockDim.x){
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what the problem is? How many beamlets? Will it fit into per thread cache?

Comment: I would suggest reading a good CUDA tutorial; no-one is going to write your code for you!

Comment: @Oli I do not expect someone else writes the code for me, I only want to know how to make those loops fitting into a GPU kernel. And yes, a good CUDA tutorial would be great, but I have not found any tutorial talking about nested for loops translation

Comment: Nested loops? Matrix multiplication comes to mind. http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/~kindr/projects/hpca/files/NCSA_GPU_tutorial_d3.pdf

Comment: It's not clear to me if you realize that by starting the threads on the GPU you already initiate a number of loops, e.g. one thread for each fragment. The value threadId tells you where you are in the image.

Comment: How big is Nmax?  Currently you have parallelism of 5 * 200 * Nmax.  If Nmax is small (< 10), then you don't have a ton of parallelism.  If it is larger than that, you have a lot more and therefore more flexibility in how you parallelize it.

Comment: Nmax is around 600, what would you suggest to do instead?

Comment: To be honest, I do not think I can achive a good paralelization on the way I have implemented it as is current the main index used inside of the loops, that is what concern me the most...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this idea. But you might need to do some minor modifications based on your code.

```
dim3 blocks(NoOfThreads, 1);
dim3 grid(Nbeans, 1);

kernel<<grid, blocks, 1>>()

__global__ kernel()
{
   int noOfBlocks = ( NbeamletsPerbeam[blockIdx.x] + blockDim.x -1)/blockDim.x;

   for(int j=0; j< noOfBlocks;j++){
     //  use threads and compute.... 
     if( (threadIdx.x * j) < NbeamletsPerbeam[blockIdx.x]) {
       current = (threadIdx.x * j) + ptr;

       for(int k=0;k<Nmax;k++){
          ......
       }

       ptr+=NbeamletsPerbeam[blockIdx.x];
    }
 }   
}
```

This should do the trick and gives you better parallelization.